# Definition of the get method in Sinatra (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In the ruby code below:

```
require 'sinatra'

class Stream
   def each
     100.times { |i| yield "#{i}\n" }
   end
 end

 get ('/') {Stream.new}
 get '/' do
   Stream.new
 end
```

The code in line #9 and the code in lines #10-12 are functionally equivalent.

The code in line #9 looks ok. It must be a decent function with the argument '/' inside paranthesis and the code inside the curly braces.

But what is that in lines #10-12, there's no paranthesis for the argument '/'. Is it still a function? If it's function why does its argument  not contain paranthesis ?

When I browse the   ~/.rbenv/versions/custom-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.4/lib/sinatra/base.rb where this "get" is defined, I find this:

```
       # Defining a `GET` handler also automatically defines
       # a `HEAD` handler.
       def get(path, opts = {}, &block)
         conditions = @conditions.dup
         route('GET', path, opts, &block)

         @conditions = conditions
         route('HEAD', path, opts, &block)
       end
```

It looks like "get" is defined optionally as  {} or &block, why is that so?

When something's defined as a block, is it a requirement of Ruby not to have any parenthesis around the argument?

Comment: A basic Ruby tutorial would probably answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment but I already have a (printed) Ruby book and it's hard to find information about this particular subject :)

Comment: The information for that particular subject, is the same in all Ruby tutorials as they discuss methods, passing parameters to them, and using blocks with methods. Sinatra isn't doing anything different, it's using Ruby's basic building blocks.

Comment: If any of these answered your question, please mark them as the Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Simone pointed out, parentheses are optional in ruby, so your `get` method can be called either with or without the parentheses.

> It looks like "get" is defined optionally as {} or &block, why is that so?

The `get` function takes three parameters. The first parameter is the `path`, the second is a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html) with a default value of empty, and the third is a block.

Blocks in ruby can be written as `{}` or as `do...end`. So in both of your examples you are passing a block to the `get` function

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby parenthesis around methods are optional. Once you define

```
def foo(path)
end
```

You can call the method in the following ways:

```
foo "/"
foo("/")
```

Likewise, there are two blocks syntaxes. The `{}` and the `do...end`.

```
def foo(path, &block)
end

foo "/" { 'bar' }

foo "/" {
  'bar'
}

foo "/" do
  'bar'
end

foo("/") { 'bar' }

foo("/") {
  'bar'
}

foo("/") do
  'bar'
end
```

are all equivalents. In reality, there are some minor differences if you consider the precedence of `{}` compared to `do...end`, but nothing you should worry about in your example.

Comment: Everything's ok except using the {} without paranthesis in argument. I've just tried it. I made: 
    get "/" {Stream.new}
and it raises:
    syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting end-of-input
It looks like, the {} requires paranthesis for the argument whereas the do...end doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Thoughtbot wrote an excellent blog that explains [how to build your own Sinatra from scratch](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/lets-build-a-sinatra).  It answers many of the questions you have.

Gabe-Berke Williams goes through step-by-step and extends functionality from a small 15 line class.  At first you use standard method names, then add functionality (params, Rack router, etc), then you create a Delegator that allows you to use get, post, etc in the global namespace.

Comment: The question isn't about sinatra at all. It's about the very ruby basics.